# Relating two shield UI ASP.NET Charts

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

I want to create two related Shield UI ASP.NET charts. When the users clicks on the first one, the data on the second one to be changed. I looked at the available events in my Visual Studio, however what i find are events related to the data binding, loading and so on. I also see there is a group of properties- ClientEvents. And for the SeriesClick event i declare the SeriesClickFunction. Which is located in my C# code:

```
    protected void SeriesClickFunction() { 
    }
```

However when i run my application in debug mode and put a break on that function, it never gets triggered. Why is that? How could I actually take use of these events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the C# code module you may not place the ClientEvents functionality. What you need is to place it on the HTML source of your page. Here is one good example of how you may relate two charts in the manner you want:

https://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/rangebar-chart/related-charts